# Android: Correct MIME type to select ttf font in SAF

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, truetype

I am trying to send intent to open a ttf file in SAF like this. I doesn't work.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("application/x-font-ttf");
            startActivityForResult(intent, FONT_SELECT_CODE);
```

Is there a MIME type for ttf files, or can I create a custom one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to get, but ttf MIME types are officially `application/font-sfnt`

Comment: "I am trying to send intent to open a ttf file in SAF like this" -- that code is not part of the Storage Access Framework. That would be `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. You might also see what `MimeTypeMap` reports as a MIME type for the `.ttf` extension, as many apps will rely upon `MimeTypeMap` for identifying the MIME types of semi-random files.

Comment: dupe with - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034375/how-to-send-an-intent-to-select-ttf-file-with-any-file-explorer. "application/x-font-ttf" is the right mime type of ttf (at least it works), so not likely the OP issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it didn't work at the time I posted this question, but 
`"application/x-font-ttf"` is the correct mime-type and works now.