# Trouble with ACTION_GET_CONTENT and TTF files

Tags: android, mime-types

I'm trying to let the user select TTF files in Android using an Intent, but the native document picker that opens when using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has several really annoying issues:

1. Selecting *Downloads* or *Recent* in the native Android document picker's navigation drawer never shows any TTF files whatsoever, even when using the mime type `*/*`.
2. The *Downloads* section doesn't even show any folders, where the user might have some fonts stored (most probably after unpacking a ZIP file in the downloads folder). Again, the mime type doesn't change this behavior.
3. Using the mime type `application/x-font-ttf` (proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11035147/2964379) for example) always leaves all TTF files greyed out. The best thing I can currently get is `application/*`, but it includes a huge range of other files, e.g. PDF, ZIP and APK.

Is there any way to fix ANY of the above issues? If not, is there a way to at least hide the clearly broken *Downloads* and *Recent* for issues 1. and 2. and maybe some magic trick to exclude(!) mime types for issue 3., or heck, just an intent to open file managers?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, currently there doesn't seem to be a real solution. The best I could think of for now is to use `application/*` and check whether the file the user selects can be made to a `Typeface` using `Typeface.createFromFile`. If the method returns `null` or `Typeface.DEFAULT` or throws an exception, the file is not a font. If it does return something, I know that at least it's a font, but not whether it is a TTF. Then I *assume* that it's a TTF if the extension is `.ttf`, and in all other cases I ask the user: "Is this really a TTF?" and trust his/her answer. Whether it *really* is a TTF in the end is only found out on the server side.